# Issue lies with variable definition. I am unsure how to resolve

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

I am trying to use a regular expression to pull the date from a text file. 
example of Date Line in text file:

```
1530Z   1 FEB 1990
```

Regex expression used:

```
date_matcher = re.compile("^([0-9]{4}[z].[0-9]+.[A-Z]{3}.[0-9]{4})")
```

I've tried to modify the code that I am using to then "pull" the date and time out of the regex expression. This is that code:

```
# get just the data lines, without headers.
def get_data_lines( path ):

     # where we are putting data lines (no header lines)
     data_lines = []

     #for root, dirs,  files in os.walk(path):
         #print oot, dirs, dirs2, files
     if os.path.isfile(str(path)) and (str(path.endswith('.dat'))):
         with open(path) as f:
             dt = None
             for line in f:

                 # check that line isn't empty
                 if line.strip():

                     # the compiled matcher will return a match object
                     # or null if no match was found.
                     result = data_matcher.match(line)
                     if result:
                         data_lines.append((line,dt))
                     else:
                         dtres = date_matcher.match(line)
                         if dtres:
                             line = [ w for w in line.split() if w]
                             date = line[-4:]
                             if len(date) == 4:
                                 time, day, month, year = date
                                # print date
                                 # fix the date bits
                                 time  = time.replace('Z','')
                                 day   = int(day)
                                 month = strptime(month,'%b').tm_mon
                                 year  = int(year)

                                 hour, minutes = re.findall('..',time)
                                 dt = datetime(year,month,day,int(hour),int(minutes))

     return data_lines
```

dt = datetime(year,month,day,int(hour),int(minutes)) is all one line but it doesn't look that way while I'm formatting it so I thought that would be helpful to point out.

I KNOW the issue is with dt = None. when I have it print out all of the dates from the directory of files that I am pulling it only prints NONE for as many files as I have dates for.

Expected result was for the dt variable to be created as empty and be replaced with dates as it encounters them. 
So for this example what I want is : `1530   1 2 1990`
for the line : `1530Z   1 FEB 1990` 
And be able to call the month, day, year, time from a given object that I have assigned it t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution where I changed the regex pattern. I replaced it with `date_matcher = re.compile(r"((\d{4})[Z]).*(\d{1,2}).(\w{3}).(\d{4})")`, which should give you the results you're looking for.

From here, I used `re.sub` to simply make the dates look like what you wanted (i.e. much more readable than the original). It removes the Z character, changes the month name to the corresponding month number, and removes the extra whitespace in the middle of the string.

```py
import re
from time import strptime
from datetime import datetime

data_matcher = re.compile('^(\s\s[0-2])')
date_matcher = re.compile(r"((\d{4})[Z]).*(\d{1,2}).(\w{3}).(\d{4})")

def get_data_lines( path ):

    # where we are putting data lines (no header lines)
    data_lines = []

    #for root, dirs,  files in os.walk(path):
    #print oot, dirs, dirs2, files
    if os.path.isfile(str(path)) and (str(path.endswith('.dat'))):
         with open(path) as f:
            dt = None
            for line in f:

            # check that line isn't empty
            if line.strip():

             # the compiled matcher will return a match object
             # or null if no match was found.
                result = data_matcher.match(line)

                if result:
                    dt = re.sub(r'((\d{4})[Z])', r'\2', line) #Remove Z character
                    month = date_matcher.match(line).group(4)
                    dt = re.sub(r'\b(\w{3})\b', str(strptime(month,'%b').tm_mon), line) #Change month name to number
                    dt = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', dt) #Remove extra whitespace
                    data_lines.append((line,dt))
                    print('Data Lines: ', data_lines)

                else:
                    line = [ w for w in line.split() if w]
                    date = line[-4:]

                    if len(date) == 4:
                        time, day, month, year = date
                        # print date
                        # fix the date bits
                        time  = time.replace('Z','')
                        day   = int(day)
                        month = strptime(month,'%b').tm_mon                         
                        year  = int(year)   
                        hour, minutes = re.findall('..',time)
                        dt = datetime(year,month,day,int(hour),int(minutes)) 
                        data_lines.append((line,dt))

    return data_lines
```

Comment: So the function 'def get_data_lines( path ):' does also grab data lines. I have two different regex matchers for it.
this one: data_matcher = re.compile('^(\s\s[0-2])') is for data.

Comment: Got it. I'll adjust my code to reflect this. If my answer works for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I definitely marked it as accepted. Fixing that regex had it immediately printing out the correct date. I also forgot that python starts at 0 for where I define my other variables I am pulling and not 1 for "columns in rows" EX: height = row[0:5] instead of row[1:6]
It looks like it starts to pull the correct line but cuts off some of the data.